# Using csrf-csrf get my page loading indefinitely

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I am trying to protect my site from CSRF attacks and attempting to use the [csrf-csrf](https://github.com/Psifi-Solutions/csrf-csrf) package to do so. The following code is in my app.js file:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoDBStore = require('connect-mongodb-session')(session);
const { doubleCsrf } = require("csrf-csrf");

const MONGODB_URI = ...

const app = express();
const store = new MongoDBStore({
  uri: MONGODB_URI,
  collection: 'sessions'
});

// ... some imports

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'my secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
  })
);
app.use(doubleCsrf);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  req.locals.isAuthenticated = req.session.isLoggedIn,
  req.locals.csrfToken = req.csrfToken()
  next();
})

// ... routes

mongoose
  .connect(MONGODB_URI)
  .then(result => {
    app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Then, in my forms, I add the following:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="<%= csrfToken %>">
```

However, when I refresh the page, the browser continuously tries to load without displaying any errors in the console. How can I correctly implement the CSRF token usage?